# when merging from branch, the directory that I didn't create is shown

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, merge, mergeinfo

I'm working on IntelliJ on window7.
merging from the branch on my trunk with 7 files.
but like below image, 7 files and 1 directory are displayed on changes.
this directory, I didn't create.

I think this directory isn't physical directory, it's just meta data file.
do you explain this situation and it directory's meaning?

thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2013? Please, upvote it then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a property-only change to the directory. It adds `svn:mergeinfo` property as a merge result.

[**SVNBook | Merge and previews**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo):

> The `svn:mergeinfo` property is automatically maintained by Subversion
>   whenever you run svn merge. Its value indicates which changes made to
>   a given path have been replicated into the directory in question.